# CloudSim: Monitoring the CPU utilization and the response time

Tags: cloud, performance-testing, cloudsim

How do I monitor the CPU utilization for each VM and the system response time when the cloudlets are running in constant intervals in CloudSim (for example every 5 minutes)?
I know that getTotalUtilizationOfCpu() function of VM class is used to get CPU utilization of VMs, but I don't know where to call this function.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is Java-based you can consider using [JMXMon Sample Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/) which allows collecting and plotting arbitrary [JMX Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html) so you will be able to get [System CPU Load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad()) like:

[image: JMeter JMX Java CPU Load]

For other technologies it will still be possible using [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) but it will require installation of [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) application on your CloudSim host(s).

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

CloudSim doesn't have a built-in feature to compute VM's resource utilization.
You can use CloudSim Plus for that, which is a modern version of [CloudSim](http://cloudsimplus.org) with lots of exclusive features and bug-fixes.

There is an answer to another question that is exactly what you are looking for. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527182/power-consumption-of-virtual-machine-in-cloudsim-plus-simulation-tool).